# K8s configmap for application dynamic configuration

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, configmap

I have a microservice for handling retention policy.
This application has default configuration for retention, e.g.: size for retention, files location etc.
But we also want create an API for the user to change this configuration with customized values on runtime.

I created a configmap with the default values, and in the application I used k8s client library to get/update/watch the configmap.

My question is, is it correct to use configmap for dynamic buisness configuration? or is it meant for static configuration that user is not supposed to touch during runtime?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no rules against it. A lot of software leverages kube API to do some kind of logic / state, ie. leader election. All of those require the app to apply changes to a kube resource. With that in mind do remember it always puts some additional load on your API and if you're unlucky that might become an issue. About two years ago we've been experiencing API limits exhaustion on one of the managed k8s services cause we were using a lot of deployments that had rather intensive leader election logic (2 requests per pod every 5 sec). The issue is long gone since then, but it shows what you have to take into account when designing interactions like this (retries, backoffs etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Using configMaps is perfectly fine for such use cases. You can use a client library in order to watch for updates on the given configMap, however a cleaner solution would be to mount the configMap as a file into the pod and have your configuration set up from the given file. Since you're mounting the configMap as a Volume, changes won't need a pod restart for changes to be visible within the pod (unlike env variables that only "refresh" once the pod get's recreated).

---

Let's say you have this `configMap`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: special-config
  namespace: default
data:
  SPECIAL_LEVEL: very
  SPECIAL_TYPE: charm
```

And then you mount this `configMap` as a Volume into your Pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: registry.k8s.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "ls /etc/config/" ]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        # Provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want
        # to add to the container
        name: special-config
  restartPolicy: Never
```

When the pod runs, the command `ls /etc/config/` produces the output below:

```
SPECIAL_LEVEL
SPECIAL_TYPE
```

This way you would also reduce "noise" to the API-Server as you can simply query the given files for updates to any configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
But I need to provide an API for the user to update the configmap during runtime. this is the reason I used a client library.